# Select mismatched columns and values from two exactly same spark python dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to select the mismatched columns and their values from two exactly same dataframes from different sources.

**What I have now:**

| col_1 | key_col | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | key1 | b | c | d |
| w | key2 | x | y | z |

| col_1 | key_col | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | key1 | b | p | q |
| w | key2 | x | y | z |

I have 2 dataframes with same schema from different data sources.

**What I want:**

Join (inner join) the 2 dataframes using the "key_col" as the join key and give the output in the following format:

For each row of the table obtained after the join, return the following row:

| key_col | mismatched_column_names | mismatched_values_in_first_df | mismatched_values_in_second_df |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key 1 | [col3, col4] | [c,d] | [p,q] |

I am looking for the query to do so in pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"), F.col("df1.key_col")==F.col("df2.key_col"))\
 .select("df1.key_col", *[F.when(F.col("df1."+col) != F.col("df2."+col), F.create_map("df1."+col,"df2."+col)).alias(col) for col in df1.schema.names if col!="key_col"])\
 .withColumn("merged", F.map_concat(*[F.coalesce(F.col(col), F.create_map().cast("map<string,string>")) for col in df1.schema.names if col!="key_col"]))\
 .withColumn("mismatched_column_names", F.array(*[F.when(F.col(col).isNotNull(), F.lit(col)) for col in df1.schema.names if col!="key_col"]))\
 .withColumn("mismatched_column_names", F.expr('filter(mismatched_column_names, x -> x is not null)'))\
 .withColumn("mismatched_values_in_first_df", F.map_keys("merged"))\
 .withColumn("mismatched_values_in_second_df", F.map_values("merged"))\
 .filter(F.size("mismatched_values_in_second_df") != 0)\
 .select("df1.key_col", "mismatched_column_names", "mismatched_values_in_first_df", "mismatched_values_in_second_df")\
 .show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

DF1:

[image: Input]

DF2:

[image: Input2]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Can this be done using pandas data frame?

Comment: @RahulKumar I've not worked with Pandas so I won't be able to help there. But glad it worked, consider accepting if it helped!